# @supports won't transpile in Visual Studio LESS file

Tags: css, visual-studio, less, visual-studio-2017, transpiler

When trying to use @supports in a LESS file, it won't transpile to CSS in Visual Studio.

I get a green line under the space after `@supports` saying:
Colon expected

I've tried every possible solution including `CSS.supports` (JS formatting - which compiled but didn't work) and `@@supports` which escapes the LESS `@function_name:` which the VS LESS compiler assumed it was.

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't resolve the issue in the LESS file in Visual studio because the transpiler does not seem to support `@supports` (ironically).

Instead I put the snippet in the HTML header, and eventually in it's own rare CSS file until support is fixed in VS